# Error when trying to run code using nlohmann JSON library in visual studio code (missing DLL?)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, g++, nlohmann-json

I'm trying to write a program using the [nlohmann JSON library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json), but whenever I try to run it I get the error `ERROR: During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139.`. I'm using Visual Studio Code on Windows and compiling using MinGW G++, and the build task works just fine - the error only occurs when I try to run / debug. Currently my code doesn't even use the JSON functions - when I comment out the "include" it runs fine, but triggers the error as soon as it's uncommented. I've seen issues related to the `0xc0000139` error before - it seems that it's related to a missing DLL? However, none of the issues I've seen actually explained how to fix this issue, other than using a different compiler, and I'm not sure what DLLs are missing (if any), or even how to find out. It also doesn't make much sense that it would be a DLL issue, since nlohmann JSON is a single header library.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
//#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include "JsonProcessor.h"

//using json = nlohmann::json;

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
    {
        // Program expects 1 argument - the name of a file containing JSON unit data
        if(argc < 2) {
            printUsage();
            return  JsonExitStatus::MISSINGARGUMENTS;
        }
        // Start by opening the JSON file and reading the contents into a JSON object
        std::ifstream jsonInputStream(argv[1]);
        //json j;
        //jsonInputStream >> j;

        return 0;
    }


void printUsage() {
    std::cout << "This program expects 1 command-line argument, which contains the path to a JSON file to process." << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I'd guess it's the standard library dll that you're missing and nlohmann is brining in more of the standard library even though it's header only

Comment: If that's the case, what should I do? It doesn't seem to be complaining that I'm importing <iostream> or <fstream>? I have MinGW, which I think includes the C++ standard libraries - is there some Visual Studio Code configuration I need to update to tell it where to look?

Comment: The dlls you will need are in the bin folder of mingw. You need to either have this folder listed in your OS `PATH` environment variable or put the required dlls in the same folder as your executable. This Microsoft link describes how and where your OS will search and how you can help it find the required dlls: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#search-order-for-desktop-applications)

Comment: My user PATH variable already included C:\MinGW\bin, and I've also added that path to the c_cpp_properties.json file, but no luck. I tried using a different JSON library instead, but as you said it's probably a standard library thing - I'm getting the same issue trying to use std::StringStream. Is there a way to reinstall or update the DLLs to make sure I have them all, and they are up-to-date?

Comment: My advice is to switch to use msys2 to install mingw and have an easier update path and package management. [https://www.msys2.org/](https://www.msys2.org/) if you do that I would remove all currently installed mingw versions and just go with msys2 and let it handle your dependencies using pacman

Comment: It could be that you have both 64 bit and 32 bit mingw binaries in your same path.

Comment: It could be that you have multiple versions and the wrong one is being loaded which then doesn't contain all the required symbols?